# Display block to ul based on li class using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some kind of peculiar situation.

I have this following struture

```
<div class="menu_left">
    <ul>
       <li class="current">A</li>
       <li>B</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My css is

```
.menu_left ul li ul { display:none; }
```

Now I want to display:block for the ul which has li class current. So in the above example I want to display:none for second ul but not for the first one.

To be honest, I have absolutely no clue if this can be done via css or jqyery.

Any help/hint is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `.menu_left ul li ul` statement assume you have an ul in the li of you ul, which is not the case. Also, you are saying `menu_left` using underscore, which is not the case of the HTML class `menu-left`.

Comment: also, I would use the `!important` statement to do this only in css. Here is the idea : `.menu_left ul li { display : none; } .current { display : block !important; }`. Is that you need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no CSS parent selector, there is currently no way to do this using CSS alone.

To do this using jQuery however, is simple, using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) (or [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)).

Note your CSS selector is incorrect and won't match anything as it stands:

**CSS**

```
.menu-left ul {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.menu-left li.current').closest('ul').show();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a546p3u8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using plain CSS. But you could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('ul li.current').parent().css('display', 'block');
```

This selects all `li`s having class `current` and then sets `display: block` for its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with javascript here, since there are no `:parent` CSS selector (yet):

```
$('.menu-left ul').hide(); // hide all UL
$('.menu-left li.current').parent().show(); // Show the one with .current LI
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery selector :first-of-type

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("ul:first-of-type").show();

});
```

```css
.menu-left ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="menu-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```